# Python Loops and counter

Tags: python

Here's my code;

```
mood = 0
if mood == 5: 
     mood = 4
# I don't want the mood going over four
```

Here is how the mood increases;

```
moode = raw_input("how are you").lower()
if 'bad' in moode:
    mood += 1
    print ('You have said that %s times today')%(mood)
```

The problem is that if you say it 5 times, she replies 'you have said it 5 times' but I don't want mood to go over four?

Comment: `mood` and `moode`? I hope those names are just a (bad) example and you don't use them in real code.

Comment: They are a bad example

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the value of `mood` after you increment it.

```
mood = 0
if 'bad' in moode:
    mood += 1
    if mood > 4:
        mood = 4
    print ('You have said that %s times today')%(name)
```

or as @arsajii mentioned - don't even both incrementing if it's already 4 or above

```
mood = 0
if 'bad' in moode:
    if mood < 4:
        mood += 1
    print ('You have said that %s times today')%(name)
```

Comment: Or better yet: `if mood < 4: mood += 1`.

Comment: `'bad' in mood` will never be `True` here.

Comment: mood = (mood + 1) % 4